# Docusign combined pdf - can we extract the individual documents?

Tags: docusignapi

We're looking at is downloading the combined pdf and then extracting the individual documents ( not my idea ). I tried using pdfsharp against my combined pdf, but I don't see any title information on the individual documents. I was just wondering if this is even possible. If I use pdfsharp, it can pull out all the pages, but I have no way of really knowing which pages belong with with document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create a DocuSign envelope you can read the document information from the envelope and remember the page counts for each document.  This should also work if you are using Templates.

You can use the [EnvelopeDocuments: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/) API to get the document information, which includes pages for each doc.  Then when you need to extract the individual documents from the combined PDF you'll know where to separate the individual docs.

Here's a sample API response for the list documents call:

```
{
    "envelopeDocuments": [
        {
            "availableDocumentTypes": [
                {
                    "isDefault": "true",
                    "type": "electronic"
                }
            ],
            "display": "inline",
            "documentId": "1",
            "includeInDownload": "true",
            "name": "NDA.pdf",
            "order": "1",
            "pages": "3",
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/44efc9e6-915e-4b1d-9b54-801410d6922d/documents/1"
        },
        {
            "availableDocumentTypes": [
                {
                    "isDefault": "true",
                    "type": "electronic"
                }
            ],
            "display": "inline",
            "documentId": "2",
            "includeInDownload": "true",
            "name": "House.pdf",
            "order": "2",
            "pages": "1",
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/44efc9e6-915e-4b1d-9b54-801410d6922d/documents/2"
        },
        {
            "availableDocumentTypes": [
                {
                    "isDefault": "true",
                    "type": "electronic"
                }
            ],
            "display": "inline",
            "documentId": "3",
            "includeInDownload": "true",
            "name": "contractor_agreement.docx",
            "order": "3",
            "pages": "2",
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
            "type": "content",
            "uri": "/envelopes/44efc9e6-915e-4b1d-9b54-801410d6922d/documents/3"
        },
        {
            "availableDocumentTypes": [
                {
                    "isDefault": "true",
                    "type": "electronic"
                }
            ],
            "display": "inline",
            "documentId": "certificate",
            "includeInDownload": "true",
            "name": "Summary",
            "order": "999",
            "pages": "4",
            "signerMustAcknowledge": "no_interaction",
            "type": "summary",
            "uri": "/envelopes/44efc9e6-915e-4b1d-9b54-801410d6922d/documents/certificate"
        }
    ],
    "envelopeId": "44efc9e6-915e-4b1d-9b54-801410d6922d"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [getEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get/) api has an option to download all the documents in an envelope as a zip file. You can just unzip the file and get individual documents.

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/archive
```

> Retrieve a ZIP archive that contains all of the PDF documents, the certificate, and any .WAV files used for voice authentication.

---

Here is a sample code to download zip file and unzip it using the [Docusign C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client).

Full Example [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/6039f7a919ffdfd40190d0e91041f400).

```cs
var envApi = new EnvelopesApi();

// GetDocument() API call returns a MemoryStream
var docStream = envApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "archive");
// let's save the document to local file system
string zipName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
string zipfilePath = @"C:\temp\" + zipName + ".zip";
using (var fs = new FileStream(zipfilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    docStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    docStream.CopyTo(fs);
}

string extractPath = @"c:\temp\" + zipName; 
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipfilePath, extractPath);
```

**Edit**(*By Kathy-Lori*)

For some reason, I had a problem casting the Stream to a FileStream object. What I did instead was the following:

```cs
Stream docStream = envApi.GetDocument(AccountId, envelopeId, "archive");
MemoryStream ret = new MemoryStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = docStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
   ret.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
ret.Position = 0;

using (var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\envelopeDocuments.zip", FileMode.Create)) 
{
   ret.CopyTo(fs); 
}
```

Comment: I did not know about that archive option. Good to know.

Comment: I'll present all my findings on this for the folks here and they can make a decision. It's just good to know about how to skin a cat in different ways. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Wow. I did not know there was voice authentication capabilities. I don't think we will be using that, but if we do need it for the future, it does have it.

Comment: So, the getEnvelopeDocuments call with the archive option, do I just stream the response from the call into a zip file? Is there anything special I need to do with this?

Comment: I have added the C# code to download the zip file using the  docusign API. You can find the full example [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/6039f7a919ffdfd40190d0e91041f400)

Comment: CodingDawg - it gave me an error on casting a MemoryStream to a FileStream.

Comment: I am using .net 4.5. I believe I am using 2.0.6. of eSign.

Comment: I got it to work by copying the stream into a memory stream. It worked like a champ. Got all my documents. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thats great. Please modify my answer and add the code that worked for you  so that others can benefit.