# DocuSign - RestApi v2 - download document using C#

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying to retrieve a signed document via RestAPI v2 with below code.

```
url = baseURL + "/accounts/" + "3602fbe5-e11c-44de-9e04-a9fc9aa2aad6" + "/envelopes/" + envId + "/documents/combined";
HttpWebRequest request4 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request4.Method = "GET";
request4.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
request4.Accept = "application/pdf";
request4.ContentType = "application/json";
request4.ContentLength = 0;
HttpWebResponse webResponse4 = (HttpWebResponse)request4.GetResponse();

StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(webResponse4.GetResponseStream());

StreamWriter objSW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Docusign\test_" + envId + ".pdf");
objSW.Write(objSR.ReadToEnd());
objSW.Close();    
objSR.Close();
```

With above code, I'm able to save a PDF file but something is not right. Can someone help me fix my buggy code.

Downloaded Document:
[image: Downloaded Document]

Original document:
[image: Original document]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**: You can simply use the [System.Net.WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
string url = baseURL + "/accounts/" + accountId + "/envelopes/" + envId + "/documents/combined";
string path = @"C:\Users\reddy\Desktop\Docusign\test_" + envId + ".pdf";
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
    wc.DownloadFile(url, path);
}
```

**Option 2** : Copy the input stream to the output FileStream

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = File.Create(path))
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
}
```

**Option 3** : Using the DocuSign [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client)

See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/6039f7a919ffdfd40190d0e91041f400#file-docusigndownloadzipfile-cs-L49-L65)

```
var envApi = new EnvelopesApi();
var docStream = envApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined");
using (var stream = File.Create(filePath))
    docStream.CopyTo(stream);
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43191895/1219543)

Comment: Worked well. Thank you. Do you see any issue in my above code?

Comment: Updated my answer with few other options to download documents using the docusign rest API.

Comment: Thank you. How long is an envelope valid? and for how long can we download a signed document?

Comment: A signed envelope should be valid indefinitely. You should be able to download a signed document at any time if you have access to the document.

Comment: Thank you. We are using SigniX for getting our documents eSigned and in download process, about 1% of the time they were unable to return us the signed document and for this reason, they have a Push mechanism where they send us the status by call us at a API that is when we used to download the documents. At DocuSign, do you have any similar functionality where DocuSign Notifies us about the status of document?

Comment: Can you please post this as a separate question rather than extending the conversation here.

Comment: I'll post it. But can you please refer me to some kind of documentation regarding this here. Please!

Comment: Look at DocuSign [Webhooks](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855935/docusign-document-download is my new post. Please take a look. Thanks