# DocuSign - Document Download

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use DocuSign via Rest API and ran into a question. After a user signed document and is redirected to the URL that is specified on RecipientView (/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient), Considering both best and worst case scenarios, how long should we wait before we download the signed document?

I'm asking this question because we saw some issues with SigniX in the past where, after SigniX returning the control to redirectUrl, the signed document was not available to download. Even though this happened very little number of times which might be <1% of all requests, Every single document is $$ and cannot afford to lose it.

If answer to my question is Yes, Please provide a C# example on using `webhook`.

Thanks.

Comment: **_after redirecting to the given url?_** ... Can you please elaborate on the url  you are redirecting to?  **_we saw some issues with SigniX_** .. What are those issues?

Comment: I modified my Original question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of integration between SigniX and DocuSign. You should specify more information on how you are doing this. Or Are you using SigniX and DocuSign independently. Since this is a DocuSign API question, I want to understand the role of SigniX here.

Comment: I Used SigniX as a example to explain a possible scenario. Both SigniX and Docusign are used independently on our web application.

Comment: @Reddy If you have a DocuSign account and you have access to the envelope in question (ie you sent it or you're an account admin) then you can always download the documents.  They can referenced by their unique envelopeId which is a GUID and you can download it with the right permissions.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated my question. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup DocuSign [WebHook](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks) aka Connect notifications at your account level or envelope level and automatically receive the Documents when an envelope is completed.

Here is a sample [CreateEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#webhook-options) request to setup configuration for the connect notifications per envelope level. Look at [eventNotification](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/eventNotification) property. All you have to do is host a listener to which DocuSign can send messages.

```
{
"emailSubject": "Testing connect notification",
"status": "sent",

"eventNotification": {
    "url": "<Add your listener URL here>",
    "loggingEnabled": "true",
    "requireAcknowledgment": "true",
    "envelopeEvents": [
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }
    ],
    "includeDocuments": "true"
},

"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "name": "john smith",
            "email": "johnsmith@acme.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1"
        }
    ]
},
"documents": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Contract",
        "fileExtension": "contract",
        "documentBase64": "DQoNCg0KDQogICAgICAgICBEdW1teSBDb250cmFjdA=="
    }
 ]
}
```

Here are some useful links which help you to setup your connect listener

- WebHook [c# recipe](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp)
- More Api [Recipes](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status)

Blog Posts

- [Webhooks: Don’t Poll Us, We’ll Call You!](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhooks-dont-poll-us-well-call/)
- [Adding Connect Webhooks to your Application](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/)
- [Securing Your Connect Webhook Listener](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/)

Comment: How can i request a notification on other events like "session timeout" or in a case of exception?

Comment: See the Connect [APIs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Connect/ConnectEvents/). YOu can retrieve failures using these API's

Comment: @PraveenReddy: As per documentation docusign recommends to download completed documents in webhook response for envelope level connect. If i want to load all the documents associated with an envelope wouldn't it be better to download them separately in zip file?