# Retrieve signed document using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I want to download a document signed recipient using DocuSign API (REST).
I am using the following endpoint as per the documentation.

[HTTP request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lKSs.png)

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```

Request Headers

```
X-DocuSign-Authentication:{"Username": <Username>,"Password": <Password>,"IntegratorKey": <IntegratorKey>}
Accept: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
```

I got document in a base64 format which I am able to download but when try to open that file using PDF viewer we got the following message:

The file is blank and some error related to signature, check following screenshot

[PDF open error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lKSs.png)

Are there any parameters missing while downloading the document? Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us your code to download the document.

Comment: If you are using C# SDK then see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793686/1219543

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 2):

See this link for EnvelopeId stamp control

https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-move-the-Envelope-ID-Stamp-on-my-documents

In DEMO environment you will always have the "demonstration only" stamp on the document. This will not be present when you goto prod environment

Comment: I am sending the document using REST API. Is there any way to prevent envelop Id at the top of the document?
Also, I have updated the description. will you please check?

Comment: Please show us your code to save the document. Without seeing that we cannot tell what you are doing wrong. The request header `Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64` is not required